# Mark the status from unresolved to resolved in PHP mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I have this mysql table like this:

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td>status</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Unresolvd <a href="#">Mark as resolved</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>Unresolvd <a href="#">Mark as Resolved</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to create a link near unresolved and as soon as someone clicks on it the corresponding status should change from unresolved to resolved for that particular id in mysql table. What is the best way to do it.

Comment: You are going to need pure Javascript Ajax or JQuery Ajax.. And ofcource the PHP code that handles the update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best will be using Ajax calls.On click on Anchor, Call a function containing Ajax call by sending Id of the record as a parameter to the function.

```js
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Post URL",
        data: data to send to DB,- which record to be changed
        dataType: "json", - return format
        async: "true",
        cache: "false",
        success: function (msg) {
            // On success                 
        },
        Error: function (x, e) {
            // On Error
        }
    });
```

Comment: This only works if you are using the javascript library JQuery